# Jolt not printing anything

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am writing jolt for transforming this data but not getting desired result

If `practice_loc`,`prac_num` and `topId` are same for two or more data then they will be combined together with separate **S1** and **S2** within `subList`. Else they would pass as it is with addition of subList only.

**Data**

```json
[
  {
    "practice_loc": "120",
    "prac_num": "oswal",
    "topId": "t1",
    "S1": "A1",
    "S2": "B1"
  },
  {
    "practice_loc": "120",
    "prac_num": "oswal",
    "topId": "t1",
    "S1": "A2",
    "S2": ""
  },
  {
    "practice_loc": "334",
    "prac_num": "L3",
    "topId": "plumcherry",
    "S1": "A3",
    "S2": ""
  },
  {
    "practice_loc": "987",
    "prac_num": "L3",
    "topId": "artica",
    "S1": "A5",
    "S2": "B7"
  }
]
```

**Expected Output:**

```json
[
  {
    "practice_loc": "120",
    "prac_num": "oswal",
    "topId": "t1"
    "subList": [
      {
        "S1": "A1",
        "S2": "B1"
      },
      {
        "S1": "A2",
        "S2": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "practice_loc": "334",
    "prac_num": "L3",
    "topId": "plumcherry"
    "subList": [
      {
        "SubID1": "A3",
        "SubID2": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "practice_loc": "987",
    "prac_num": "L3",
    "topId": "artica",
    "subList": [
      {
        "SubID1": "A5",
        "SubID2": "B7"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is what I tried but didnt get desired result Its not printing anything

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "@(1,practice_loc).@(1,prac_num).@(1,topId)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "MANY"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "practice_loc": "[#4].&",
            "prac_num": "[#4].&",
            "topId": "[#4].&",
            "S*": "[#4].subList[&1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "practice_loc": "ONE",
        "prac_num": "ONE",
        "topId": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current spec is pretty good. Would be suitable to rearrange it like that

```json
[
  { // group by those three attributes
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@1,practice_loc.@1,prac_num.@1,topId.&",
        "S*": "@1,practice_loc.@1,prac_num.@1,topId.subList[&1].&"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of wrappers
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE", // pick only single one from repeating components 
        "subList": "MANY"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of generated nulls within subList arrays 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit** *for illustration* : Below, I have pasted the image what I get after toggling `ADVANCED` tab of `Configure` section for the `JoltTransformJSON` processor which has the version **1.21.0** as NiFi does. Btw, yours is a recent version as well.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Barbaros   , I m getting error String cannot be cast to java.util.map,its working in jolt inception but not in my NIfi processor ,  can you write some other way possible?

Comment: Hi @dracile , what's your NiFi's version, probably it's old.

Comment: nifi version is 20

Comment: is there anyother way of writing this jolt? still getting the same error, still getting error java.lang.classException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.map

Comment: Your have a recent version also. I've edited the answer @dracile